# Angular 7 and angular material date picker is setting the button to disabled when receiving a date from mysql server

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I have a material date picker, where it is set by a value sent from mysql database.

The button is always disabled, which it should not be as the date picker already contain a value. But when I change the value to another date using the date picker, the button is enabled.

[Here is a stackblitz describing the issue.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-datepicker-rezsng)

And here the scripts (where I am using a static value of the date to simulate the same one from the server):

The value returned from the server is `2018-2-12 00:00:00` and displayed inside the date picker like `2/12/2018` on my project, but on stackblitz it is displayed as `2/12/2018 00:00:00`.

The html script:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-content>
            <h2 class="example-h2">Datepicker</h2>
            <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="outline">
                <input matInput id="date_added" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="dateFormat"
                  formControlName="date_added" placeholder="Date Added">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
 <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="updateHouseholdData()" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">
            <mat-icon>update</mat-icon>Update
          </button> 
</form>
{{formGroup.controls.date_added.errors | json}}
<br>
{{formGroup.controls.date_added.value | json}}
```

Typescript:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  dateFormat;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)
  {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      'date_added': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dateFormat = '2/14/2018 00:00:00';
  }
}
```

How to convert the date coming from mysql server to be readable by a material date picker and to make the save button enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your date into javascript date obj like this and patch To Form. Instead of setting value

Remove value from input

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.formGroup.get('date_added').patchValue(new Date('2/14/2018'));
  // this.dateFormat = '2/14/2018';
}
```